# Program to print the English word of a number

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

I've written a program which asks the user for a two-digit number and it prints out the English word for the number.
Example:

```
Enter a two digit number: 45
You entered fourty-five
```

Basically, what I have done is I've put a `switch` case for numbers 10 to 19, then used another switch case for the Ten's and another for the One's.

the problem is that after entering the number, for some reason it doesn't show anything after printing `You entered the number:`

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int Num, Tens, Ones;

    printf("Enter a Two Digit Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &Num);

    printf("You entered the number: ");

    if (10 <= Num && Num >= 19) {
        switch (Num) {
          case 10:  printf("Ten\n");        break;
          case 11:  printf("Eleven\n");     break;
          case 12:  printf("Twelve\n");     break;
          case 13:  printf("Thirteen\n");   break;
          case 14:  printf("Fourteen\n");   break;
          case 15:  printf("Fifteen\n");    break;
          case 16:  printf("Sixteen\n");    break;
          case 17:  printf("Seventeen\n");  break;
          case 18:  printf("Eighteen\n");   break;
          case 19:  printf("Nineteen\n");   break;
        }
    }
    if (20 <= Num && Num >= 99) {
        Tens = Num / 10;
        switch (Tens) {
          case 2:   printf("Twenty");   break;
          case 3:   printf("Thirty");   break;
          case 4:   printf("Fourty");   break;
          case 5:   printf("Fifty");    break;
          case 6:   printf("Sixty");    break;
          case 7:   printf("Seventy");  break;
          case 8:   printf("Eighty");   break;
          case 9:   printf("Ninety");   break;
        }
    }
    Ones = Num % 10;
    if (Ones == 0)
        printf("\n");
    else
    if (1 <= Ones && Ones >= 9) {
        printf("-");
        switch (Ones) {
          case 1: printf("One");        break;
          case 2:   printf("Two");      break;
          case 3:   printf("Three");    break;
          case 4:   printf("Four");     break;
          case 5:   printf("Five");     break;
          case 6:   printf("Six");      break;
          case 7:   printf("Seven");    break;
          case 8:   printf("Eight");    break;
          case 9:   printf("Nine");     break;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All conditions wrong...jackpot!

Comment: `(10 <= Num && Num >= 19)` do you think this can ever be true ?? You could have found out yourself  with some basic printf debugging.

Comment: You do not handle `0`.

Comment: See [fourty](http://grammarist.com/spelling/forty-fourty/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conditions are wrong and will always be false in normal execution.

Try these modification:

- `10 <= Num && Num >= 19` -> `10 <= Num && Num <= 19`
- `20 <= Num && Num >= 99` -> `20 <= Num && Num <= 99`
- `1 <= Ones && Ones >= 9` -> `1 <= Ones && Ones <= 9`

Comment: ...and `10 <= Num` --> `Num >= 10`

Comment: There is a missing test: it would print `-One` for `1`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the issues with the operators, consider replacing the `switch` with look-up tables, for the sake of performance:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void englishize (int n)
{
  static const char* const TEXTUAL_0_9 [] =
  {
    "zero",
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five",
    "six",
    "seven",
    "eight",
    "nine",
  };

  static const char* const TEXTUAL_10_19 [] =
  {
    "ten",
    "eleven",
    "twelve",
    "thirteen",
    "fourteen",
    "fifteen",
    "sixteen",
    "seventeen",
    "eighteen",
    "nineteen",
  };

  static const char* const TENS [] =
  {
    "zero",
    "ten",
    "twenty",
    "thirty",
    "forty",
    "fifty",
    "sixty",
    "seventy",
    "eighty",
    "ninety"
  };

  if((n % 10) == 0) // divisible by ten
  {
    printf("%s\n", TENS[n/10]);
    return ;
  }
  else if(n >= 20) // all numbers from 20 and above behave logically
  {
    printf("%s-%s\n", TENS[n/10], TEXTUAL_0_9[n%10]);
  }
  else if(n >= 10) // special case for numbers between 10-19
  {
    printf("%s\n", TEXTUAL_10_19[n-10]);
  }
  else // n < 10
  {
    printf("%s\n", TEXTUAL_0_9[n]);
  }
}

int main ()
{
  for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
  {
    englishize(i);
  }

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You can simplify with a single array for `0` to `19`.

Comment: @chqrlie I considered that but went with separate arrays, since the 0 to 9 one is used for two different purposes, so it seemed cleaner to keep them apart. There's likely even more effective ways to implement this btw, I just whipped something together as an alternative to the potentially far slower `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

All your conditions are incorrect. As a matter of fact, you can simplify the code and remove most of the tests:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int Num, Tens, Ones;

    printf("Enter a Two Digit Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &Num);

    printf("You entered the number: ");

    switch (Num) {
      case 0:   printf("Zero\n");       break;
      case 10:  printf("Ten\n");        break;
      case 11:  printf("Eleven\n");     break;
      case 12:  printf("Twelve\n");     break;
      case 13:  printf("Thirteen\n");   break;
      case 14:  printf("Fourteen\n");   break;
      case 15:  printf("Fifteen\n");    break;
      case 16:  printf("Sixteen\n");    break;
      case 17:  printf("Seventeen\n");  break;
      case 18:  printf("Eighteen\n");   break;
      case 19:  printf("Nineteen\n");   break;
    }

    Tens = Num / 10;
    switch (Tens) {
      case 2:   printf("Twenty");   break;
      case 3:   printf("Thirty");   break;
      case 4:   printf("Fourty");   break;
      case 5:   printf("Fifty");    break;
      case 6:   printf("Sixty");    break;
      case 7:   printf("Seventy");  break;
      case 8:   printf("Eighty");   break;
      case 9:   printf("Ninety");   break;
    }

    Ones = Num % 10;

    if (Ones > 0) {
        if (Tenths > 2)
            printf("-");
        switch (Ones) {
          case 1:   printf("One");      break;
          case 2:   printf("Two");      break;
          case 3:   printf("Three");    break;
          case 4:   printf("Four");     break;
          case 5:   printf("Five");     break;
          case 6:   printf("Six");      break;
          case 7:   printf("Seven");    break;
          case 8:   printf("Eight");    break;
          case 9:   printf("Nine");     break;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```